# Another way to print my method?

Tags: java

My program works. I was just wondering if there was a way for me to print my table by actually returning a string, and not just using System.out.print. 
In other words, I want to know if instead of having return null I can return a string that prints out my table.

```
  /**
     * Print the magic square in table form.
     */
public String toString() {

    for (int row = 0; row < (magicSquare.length); row++) {
        // row gets #row
        System.out.print("\t");
        for (int column = 0; column < (magicSquare[row].length); column++) {
            //column gets #column 
            System.out.print(magicSquare[row][column] + "\t");

            // when all column has been completed make new line
            if (column == size - 1) {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }

        }
        System.out.print("\n");

    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Short answer is yes, long answer is, replace `System.out.print` with `StringBuilder`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Will this require a lot of more code? Will it be pointless?

Comment: Nope, pretty much the same

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your answer. Can you please check my comment on your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, yes you can.  The long answer would involve replacing the `System.out.print` statements with something like `StringBuilder`, for example...

```
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);

    for (int row = 0; row < (magicSquare.length); row++) {
        // row gets #row
        sb.append("\t");
        for (int column = 0; column < (magicSquare[row].length); column++) {
            //column gets #column 
            sb.append(magicSquare[row][column] + "\t");

            // when all column has been completed make new line
            if (column == size - 1) {
                sb.append("\n");
            }

        }
        sb.append("\n");

    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Think you that what I was looking for. Just want to know what is the difference between a StringBuilder and a regular string object. Will it be possible to do the same thing with a string object.

Comment: `String` is immutable, it can't be changed, `StringBuilder` builds the `String` internally (using a `char` array).  When it comes to loops like this, it's more efficient, as the compiler won't optimize `String` concatenation, meaning that each time you "add" a `String` (`string = string + "blah"`)  you're actually creating upwards of 3 new, temporary `String` objects.  This can place a burden on the system as these objects need to be created, place on the heap and disposed of repeatedly in short order.

Comment: It's commonly good practice to use `StringBuilder` when you're performing `String` concatenation within a loop to avoid these overheads.

Comment: `StringBuilder` will also allow you to manipulate the contents (add, insert, remove) more easily and efficiently then `String` alone

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I actually tried both ways, stringbuilder and string object, and the the stringbuilder was bit faster. Which doesn't really effect my program, but might affect future programs. Anyways, thank you for all your help.